# Prove that a subset is a subspace (classic one)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a subset S, $$ S =  \left\{ f \in  \mathbb{R}^{ \mathbb{R} } : f(1) = 1 + f(0)  \right\}  \subset \mathbb{R}^ \mathbb{R}  $$
the goal is to check whether S is a subspace or not.

I already know that it's not a subspace, but my questions are:

1. Why does the element $0$ doesn't belong to S? Isn't the function $f(0) = 0$ $\subset$ S? (e.g. f(x)=x) [I.e. what is the element $0$ in concrete and how I can I tell which element is the element $0$? (is it when x + (element zero) = x? My guess in this case would be f(x) = 0; nevertheless I would like to hear some clear explanation];
2. Can I prove S isn't closed under addiction as it follows?:$f(1)+g(1)=(f+g)(1)=(f+g)(0)+2  \not \subset S$ (because it's adding two and not one it doesn't belong to S)
3. Why is not $\alpha$f(x)=($\alpha$f)(x) true? Isn't it trivial?

Thanks in advance, I'm really trying to get into Linear Algebra...

Comment: Let $f_0(x)=0$ for all $x$. $f_0\notin S$ because $f_0(1)=0\ne 1+0=1+f_0(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

1. If $f$ is the null function, then $f(1)=0\ne1=1+f(0)$. So, $f\notin S$.
2. No, you cannot. Asserting that $(f+g)(0)+2\not\subset S$ makes no sense, since $(f+g)(0)+2$ is a real number, not a set of functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.
3. *Of course* that $\alpha f(x)=(\alpha f)(x)$; that's how $\alpha f$ is defined. What is *not* true in general is that if $f\in S$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then $\alpha f\in S$.

Comment: Professor José grato pela resposta, como deve imaginar iniciei há pouco tempo o estudo da álgebra linear e portanto não é algo que ainda domine. No caso da primeira pergunta, a dificuldade foi perceber que o elemento $0$ de um conjunto é o elemento que quando somado com qualquer outro elemento dá esse mesmo elemento (neste caso, f(x)=$0$). Quanto à segunda e terceira pergunta, percebi as suas anotações e fiquei muito mais elucidado; no entanto não vejo outra forma de provar que o subconjunto não é fechado relativamente à adição e multiplação sem ser através de casos concretos. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: What's wrong with using concrete cases? That's what I would do.

Comment: Imaginando que se pretendia provar que $ \forall f,g  \in S, (f+g)(x) \subset S $ , haveria alguma forma possível de o fazer, neste caso? (Ou para o caso do fecho da multiplicação)

Comment: But in this case we can't do that, since what happens is that $(\exists f,g\in S):f+g\notin S$. So, providing a concrete example is enough.